# Access Violation Calling Non-Exported DLL Function C++

Tags: c++, assembly, reverse-engineering, access-violation

I'm trying to access an non-exported function in a DLL for experimental purposes. Without discussing the obvious reasons why this is a bad idea...

I believe I have worked out correct function prototype, and I can confirm the code is jumping to offset in module I want.

The C++ code is

```
typedef int (__stdcall *FN)(int,wchar_t *);

const DWORD_PTR funcOffset = 0x6F5B9;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FN myFunction;
    DWORD dwResult;
    HMODULE hModule=LoadLibrary(L"undocumented.dll");

if (hModule != NULL)
{
    DWORD_PTR funcAddress = (DWORD_PTR)GetProcAddress(hModule, "DllRegisterServer") + funcOffset;
    myFunction = (FN)funcAddress;
    wchar_t input[] = L"someinputdata";
    int result = myFunction(0,input);
    std::cout << "Result: " << result << std::endl;
}
else
{
    dwResult = GetLastError();
    std::cerr << "Failed: " << dwResult << std::endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

The function jumps to offset, but I get an access violation at mov [esi+8], eax. What can I do to prevent this

```
mov     edi, edi
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
sub     esp, 0Ch
cmp     [ebp+<wchar_t *>], 0
push    esi
mov     esi, ecx
jz      short <some location> ; doesn't jump
push    [ebp+<wchar_t *>]     
call    ds:_wcsdup
mov     [esi+8], eax <- access violation
```

Ecx is set in call ds:_wcsup:

```
__wcsdup:
75DBEFA3  mov         edi,edi  
75DBEFA5  push        ebp  
75DBEFA6  mov         ebp,esp  
75DBEFA8  cmp         dword ptr [ebp+8],0  
75DBEFAC  je          __wcsdup+2161Ah (75DE05BDh)  
75DBEFB2  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
75DBEFB5  push        edi  
75DBEFB6  xor         edi,edi  
75DBEFB8  lea         edx,[ecx+2]  
75DBEFBB  mov         ax,word ptr [ecx]  
75DBEFBE  add         ecx,2  
75DBEFC1  cmp         ax,di  
75DBEFC4  jne         __wcsdup+18h (75DBEFBBh)  
75DBEFC6  sub         ecx,edx  
75DBEFC8  sar         ecx,1  
75DBEFCA  push        ebx  
75DBEFCB  push        2  
75DBEFCD  lea         ebx,[ecx+1]  
75DBEFD0  push        ebx  
75DBEFD1  call        _calloc (75DBBE55h)  
75DBEFD6  mov         edi,eax  
75DBEFD8  pop         ecx  
75DBEFD9  pop         ecx  
75DBEFDA  test        edi,edi  
75DBEFDC  je          __wcsdup+2161Eh (75DE05C1h)  
75DBEFE2  push        dword ptr [ebp+8]  
75DBEFE5  push        ebx  
75DBEFE6  push        edi  
75DBEFE7  call        _wcscpy_s (75DBBB70h)  
75DBEFEC  add         esp,0Ch  
75DBEFEF  test        eax,eax  
75DBEFF1  jne         __wcsdup+5626Fh (75E15212h)  
75DBEFF7  mov         eax,edi  
75DBEFF9  pop         ebx  
75DBEFFA  pop         edi  
75DBEFFB  pop         ebp  
75DBEFFC  ret
```

Comment: I don't know x86 assembler very well; where is `ecx` being set? (Its value gets put into `esi`, which is the address at which the AV occurs.) Is it possible that you've jumped into the middle of the function instead of to the pre-amble? Is it possible that the calling convention isn't `__stdcall`?

Comment: Are you sure your offset is correct? Adding `0x6F5B9` to `fn` will not advance `fn` by `0x6F5B9` bytes, but by `0x6F5B9*sizeof(DWORD)` bytes.

Comment: ecx is set at call    ds:_wcsdup

Comment: I stepped through the disassembly, and it matched the function that I wanted to call.

Comment: @MalcolmMcCaffery No, Cameron is talking about the value of `ecx` that gets copied into `esi` prior to the `_wcsdup` call.

Comment: It is set to 0 before that.

Comment: @Malcolm: Well, that explains the access violation then. You can't write to address 8!

Comment: @MalcolmMcCaffery - So `esi` is 0?  Before going further, can you post the *exact* error message you're getting when you run your program?

Comment: Possibly the calling convention is actually MS fastcall, and the function actually takes at least three arguments. MS fastcall passes the first two arguments in ECX and EDX and the rest on the stack. That could explain why the function is reading from ECX without putting anything there itself, and also referencing stack arguments.

Comment: Ok thanks, yes I will check this function more carefully in actual program . Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @MalcolmMcCaffery - Let me ask a very basic question.  Why do you need to access an unexported DLL function?  Did you write the DLL?  If not, you know there could be legal aspects of attempting to use the DLL in other ways other than the documented usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear from the assembly that this code expects a meaningful value in `ECX`.

```
mov     edi, edi
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
sub     esp, 0Ch
cmp     [ebp+<wchar_t *>], 0
push    esi
mov     esi, ecx  !! ecx has not been written to before here, now it is read
```

You believe that the function is `stdcall`. And for an `stdcall` function, the value of `ECX` is ill-defined on entry. So I'd say that it is pretty clear that the function is not `stdcall`. The only obvious sign of an input argument being used is that use of `ECX`. So I'd say that this is a `thiscall` member function that passes the `this` pointer in `ECX`.

Note that I could not be 100% sure about all of the above. Reverse engineering is hard enough at the best of times and do bear in mind that we are working with just the information that you provided.

Comment: The issue is definitely __stdcall is wrong choice. I will workout the correction option. A new prototype using __fastcall (and additional input parameter) removes the access violation) Now warned The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call, this points to more research needed on correct calling pattern.

Comment: Further research identified that most likely the calling convention is __thiscall. Using this prototype eliminated crashing AND ESP error. typedef int (__thiscall *FN)(wchar_t * ,wchar_t *, wchar_t *); - Although further research is required to identify the "class" structure used. With the tip to check ECX I found __thiscall was the other calling convention utilizing ECX: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx

Comment: For now I have the function partially working passing first parameter a struct struct1 {
 char something[8];
 wchar_t * iValue;} <- the output I was looking for esi+8, is pointer to a string that gets set here